# How do i avoid loading child widget each time i switch between different Parent widget? and just load the child widget only once the page loads?

Tags: flutter

I dont have a lot of experience in flutter just started through

selectedCardIndex // this comes from top. tripType is updated from Flights.

```
if (widget.selectedCardIndex == 0 && tripType == 0)
  FlightRoundTripContainer(
    tripType: tripType,
    selectedCardIndex: widget.selectedCardIndex,
    citiesItems: widget.citiesItems,
    ...
  ),
if (widget.selectedCardIndex == 0 && tripType == 1)
  FlightsMultiCityContainer(
    tripType: tripType,
    selectedCardIndex: widget.selectedCardIndex,
    citiesItems: widget.citiesItems,
    ...
  ),
if (widget.selectedCardIndex != 0)
  TravelOtherModeContainer(
    selectedCardIndex: widget.selectedCardIndex,
    citiesItems: widget.citiesItems,
    ...
  ),
```

citiesItems this is about 2200 city (API is only called once, just passing from parent), with 6 accompanied data like REGION, CATEGORY etc.
these cards are mix of dropdowns and datetime inputs.
Where I am saving it in different lists.

```
InputDropdown(
  label: Strings.fromPlace,
  items: citiesItems,
  onChanged: (value) {
    roundTripFlight[0].locationEnd = value;
    roundTripFlight[1].locationBegin = value;
  },
),
```

Problem is it takes approx. 6-7s to switch between trip and index.
If this could be because of huge API data, what could I do to make it faster?

**Solution ** I think of if this is possible:
render the InputDropdown widget only once with citiesItems and just change label and onChange and use it everywhere? if yes how can I approach it?